# What's wrong in my low-pass filter design?

Tags: filter, design, transfer-function

I use the magnitude of the transfer fuction $$\lvert{H(\omega)}\rvert = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\omega RC)^2}}\
$$ to calculate the wanted output/input ratio at 0.1.

I use R = 1 kΩ and C = 0.5 μF for a 20 kHz noise input.

Why do I get nearly nothing for the simulation output?

According to my calculation, it should be 0.1 V if my input voltage amplitude is 1 V.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add an image of the input and output. Please also show the result when you input a 1Hz signal. What was the value of \$\omega\$ used when the output/input was set as 0.1 ?

Comment: Where did you get that transfer function? A simplified sanity check: Xc @ 20k = 16 ohms (Rf is negligible). Output ratio = 16/1k = 16 mV

Comment: Plugging the numbers into that transfer function gives an output of 15.9mV. I think you've forgotten to square the wRC part.

Comment: "*According to my calculation*" -- can you show those? Since you're not getting what you're expecting, it's possible that your calculations are wrong. Or you expectations.

Comment: Don't even have to use the full transfer function: the impedance of a 0.5uF capacitor at 20kHz is 1/sC = 1/(2*pi*20000*0.5e-6) = 16 ohms, so the gain of the first stage is only 16/1000 at that frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the transfer function of the circuit is given by:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\left(-\frac{1}{\text{R}_1}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{\text{s}\text{C}}\cdot\text{R}_2}{\frac{1}{\text{s}\text{C}}+\text{R}_2}\right)\cdot\left(-\frac{\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3}\right)=\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_3}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\text{s}\text{C}\text{R}_2}\tag1$$

Notice that when \$\text{R}_1=\text{R}_2=\text{R}_3=\text{R}_4\$, we get:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{1}{1+\text{s}\text{C}\text{R}_2}\tag2$$

So, we get:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\omega\text{C}\text{R}_2\right)^2}}\tag3$$

Using your values we get:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\underbrace{2\pi\cdot20\cdot1000}_\text{frequency}\cdot\underbrace{1\cdot1000}_\text{resistor}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\cdot10^{-6}}_\text{capacitor}\right)^2}}=$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+400 \pi ^2}}\approx0.0159135\tag4$$

So, when the input amplitude is \$1\space\text{V}\$ at the output we get \$\approx0.0159135\space\text{V}\$.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the OP's question at all, is inconsistent with the OP's reported output, and is inconsistent with the estimates made by several others in the comments.

Comment: @jan's equations are ok, just the reduction in (4) is wrong. Its is (1+(20pi)^-2

Comment: @HenningLarsen Sorry, I edited my answer.

Comment: An opamp cannot drive a capacitor reactance as low as 16 ohms. A power amplifier is needed to do it. Since the noise is only at 20kHz then why not make a 20kHz notch filter with normal parts values?

Comment: Sorry but what you post is good mathematics but that's not the way to tame circuits. In this specifically case it all boils down to DC gain -1×-1=1 and a pole in 1k × 0.5u=500us. Any algebra more complicated than this is just smoke in the eyes, it's only noise obscuring the real problem ( BTW if you write H(s) there can't be jw on the other side of =  )